# Outlook .VotingOptions = not working anymore

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I created this file that sends like a receipt and a approval/reject to our plant manager through outlook whenever we request transportation or whatever. Here's the problem. Its been working great for years but recently, it just stopped sending the voting option in the mail. I F8 Through the code and it picks msg.VotingOptions = "Accept;Reject" as a string, which is correct. sends the mail, but when it arrives. Nothings there. My .priority 2 works, etc.

Did something change with how it works? did they rename the code line to something else?
Anyone know?

Sincerely yours

```
    Option Explicit

Sub Send_Mails()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA")
Dim i As Integer

Dim OA As Object
Dim msg As Object

Set OA = CreateObject("outlook.application")

Dim last_row As Integer
last_row = Application.CountA(sh.Range("N:N"))

For i = 2 To last_row
Set msg = OA.createitem(0)
msg.to = sh.Range("N" & i).Value
msg.CC = sh.Range("O" & i).Value
msg.Subject = sh.Range("P" & i).Value
msg.body = sh.Range("Q" & i).Value
msg.VotingOptions = "Accept;Reject"
msg.Importance = 2

If sh.Range("R" & i).Value <> "" Then
    msg.attachments.Add sh.Range("R" & i).Value


End If

msg.send

Next i

MsgBox "All the mails have been sent successfully"


End Sub
```

Comment: It works for me. I can see the result in the subject as well as in the `Clickable The sender responded` section as well. Did the person actually vote or just clicked on "Reply"? What do you see in the subject of the email that you received?